# Reading secrets in Azure Synapse from Azure Key Vault using Python SDK and user- or system-assigned managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-managed-identity, azure-python-sdk

I wrote a python script and hosted it on Azure Synapse as an Apache Spark job definition. The script has to get a secret from an Azure Key Vault to function.

While developing, I used VS Code authentication and everything ran smoothly. I used this authentication method:

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True)

client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credential)
retrieved_secret = client.get_secret(secret_name)
```

When I put the code in a Synapse job, I tried using system- and user-assigned managed identities to no avail. When using the former, I didn't change anything in the code above. For the latter, I provided the Client ID of the user-assigned identity:

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(
            exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True,
            managed_identity_client_id=r"xxxxxxxx"
        )
```

I also tried using the following, which was nonetheless fruitless:

```
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential() # system-assigned identity
credential = ManagedIdentityCredential(
            client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") # user-assigned identity
```

In all cases, I keep receiving these errors in the cloud but not locally as said:

```
azure.identity._exceptions.CredentialUnavailableError: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3182fccbb0>, 'Connection to 169.254.169.254 timed out. (connect timeout=0.3)')
```

I find contradicting information regarding whether Synapse supports managed identity credentials. [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/identity/identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#troubleshoot-managed-identity-authentication-issues) it says no, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-status#:%7E:text=The%20following%20Azure%20services%20support%20managed%20identities%20for%20Azure%20resources%3A) yes.

I checked that the user-assigned identity is attached to Synapse workspace, and that proper IAM roles and access policies are correctly set on the key vault to allow the job to get a secrete from it, and am hitting a wall at the moment.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This article explain how to enable managed identity on synapse: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity?tabs=synapse-analytics

Comment: And this article explain how to get credentials from key vault usiong a linked service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I missed the linked service part.

Comment: @Thomas I got the chance to test the whole app and it seems I still get `ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no response from the IMDS endpoint` even though the key vault is linked to Synapse and I can successfully test the integration. Do I have to change anything in my code too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up getting the secrets from the Synapse linked service which connects Synapse workspace and the key vault instead of referring to the key vault directly:

```
session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
token_library = (session._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.
                             tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary)
retrieved_secret = token_library.getSecret(
                kv_name, secret_name, linked_service)
```

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/secure-data-warehouse-azure-synapse-analytics/8-implement-encryption), section *Securing your credentials through linked services with TokenLibrary for Apache Spark*.

Comment: Thank you for this question and answer this worked like a charm for us as well. We now use the same setup.

Comment: @AlexanderKvist you are welcome! Glad it helped you guys :)